# Creating a command in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a simple script:

```
echo "the path of the current directory is `pwd`"
```

and saved it by the name `pathinfo`

then i have created a bin directory at my home page with path as 
`/home/vpnsadmin/bin`
and copied my script(pathinfo) to that bin directory.

Now i want run this script as a command but it is showing error

`-bash: /usr/bin/test2: No such file or directory`

but if copy my script(pathinfo) to "/usr/bin/" then it runs as a command.

the PATH environment variable is set as-

```
PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/vpnsadmin/bin
```

My question is why does the shell not run it as a command when it is present in `/home/vpnsadmin/bin`.
or else 
why does it only check for the binary at `/usr/bin` and not at `/home/vpnsadmin/bin` or at `/bin`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I m new to scripting and linux.

Comment: Did you `chmod +x pathinfo` to make the script executable?

Comment: yes i did that. that is why only it was running when i copied that to /usr/bin

Comment: Also try `type -a pathinfo test2` to see where bash thinks they are

Comment: -bash: type: pathinfo: not found
test2 is /home/vpnsadmin/bin/test2
This was the output when i typed the above command.

Comment: And when i removed test2 from /home/vpnsadmin/bin i.e. my script is now present only at the address /home/vpnsadmin/test2, then the output of the above command is:-
-bash: type: pathinfo: not found
-bash: type: test2: not found

Answer (score 3):

The shell that is to execute your command needs to have the correct PATH variable set *at the time of execution* and, depending on shell, might need to have created its own internal (hash)map of the available commands.

Assuming you are using bash, try the following with your script saved in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ PATH=/ test2

$ PATH=/usr/bin test2
```

In the first case you should get an expected "not found" error, in the second it should work. The third test to perform is left as an exercise...

And I have to say that the supplied error message looks a bit odd if you actually tried to do

```
$ test2
```

and not

```
$ /usr/bin/test2
```

before copying the command to `/usr/bin`.

**Edit:**

Also, avoid naming your scripts test, in any way shape or form. This causes so much confusion for beginners.

Hint:

`man test`

Comment: You were right for the first two cases. But in the third case the problem is exactly what is asked. The supplied error message is "-bash: /usr/bin/test2: No such file or directory"
that is what i dont understand.

Comment: yeah thanks for that. Actually first i named it test and then edited to test2. But i will take care of that from next time.

Comment: Actually my questions is that bash shell should search for the binary at all paths provided in the PATH env variable. But it is not doing that and only restricted to /usr/bin

Comment: @jayant Did you perform the third test? Also, is the execute bit set on the '/home/vpnsadmin/bin` directory?

Comment: yo...i performed the third test and the execute bit is set there.

Comment: do you mind answering....
What is the resulr on your bash shell screen when you type this "jhvasd"...???

Comment: @jayant The third test is `PATH=/home/vpnsadmin/bin test2` with test2 placed in this directory. If this does not work, something not related to the shell is the problem. I do not have easy access to a bash shell at the moment, but I'd expect something like "/bin/bash: no command jhvasd found in <insert PATH here>".

Comment: With this command the script is running fine.
And when i am typing anything arbitrarily then it is saying
-bash: asdas: command not found
But when i m typing test2 then it is saying
-bash: /usr/bin/test2:no such file or directory

Comment: Hey after i typed the command given by you, if remove test2 from /home/vpnsadmin/bin and copy to /usr/bin then it is not working.Now it is just looking for that script in /home/vpnsadmin/bin and not in /usr/bin.
Can you explain that..?

Comment: @jayant If you set your PATH to something that is NOT including /usr/bin, things will not work as usual. Could you please post _all of your script_ in some way since this looks more and more as if your script is started but something in it tries to execute a command that is not in PATH. And, to avoid confusion, my suggested tests are to be run _as one line_, not one setting PATH and then trying to execute your script.

Comment: @HonkyTonk...i have just copied my script from this link
http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch04sec12.html

Comment: Yeah tested them as one line only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the path to bash at the top of your script and did you use backticks around pwd?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "the path of the current directory is `pwd`"
```

Did you make the file executable?

```
chmod +x pathinfo
```

Comment: atually the problem is not with the script. the script is running fine when i am directly running it but it is not running when it present in one of the paths set in PATH environment varialbe other than "/usr/bin"

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: What shell do you use? Eg `ps $$` or `echo $SHELL` ? Some shells (like `zsh`) requires you to run `rehash`  (a shell builtin) to update their table of commands...

Comment: /bin/bash this the shell i am using

Answer (score 0):

There is another script `pathinfo` somewhere in your path which contains a call to `/usr/bin/test2`

Try `whereis pathinfo` to see how many there are and `which pathinfo` to see which one your shell currently prefers.

Comment: there is no output of the "whereis pathinfo" command or "locate pathinfo" command.